# Which preposition is best suited, 'IN' or 'OF'

Tags: prepositions

Which one is more accurate?

> I will be the lighthouse **of** your ocean.

OR

> I will be the lighthouse **in** your ocean.

Comment: of or for, maybe even beside, but not in, because it would be submersed

Comment: I'd first ask myself if lighthouse was really what I meant. Lighthouses can have two main functions; as a warning light to keep clear of danger or indicating safe entrance to harbour. It can mean danger, or safety. Lighthouses at harbours are often refered to as 'harbour lights' https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=harbour+light&title=Special:Search&go=Go&searchToken=4rmac43p2601aksl4qrnsdfti perhaps you could say 'I will be your harbour Light' The presence of sea or ocean being pretty much implied.

Comment: One lighthouse for a whole ocean? Pretty tall order.

Comment: This is a proofreading question, which are off-topic here. What did your research show you about this? What are your own theories and questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also say:

I will be the lighthouse **to** your ocean"

It's a kind of poetic metaphoric device but I'm not sure why it is structured this way.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a lighthouse is to guide ships and boats, enabling them to avoid dangers such as rocks and reefs, and to reach safety by steering the correct course into harbour. It also lets mariners know exactly where they are.

In offering to be somebody's lighthouse you are offering to be a guide to that person, warn him or her of dangers and generally keep them safe. You are somebody the person can look to if troubled or uncertain where to go or what to do. Perhaps, like many lighthouses, you stand upon a rock, while the other person drifts.

The ocean represents "troubles" and the lighthouse represents "guide".

So would you offer to be a guide of somebody's troubles or a guide in somebody's troubles?  You are a guide to the person *in* his or her troubles, you are guiding your friend, you are not guiding his or her troubles, you are not the guide *of* his or her troubles. The correct thing to say is that you are a guide to someone in troubles.

Transposing the intention of the metaphor "guide in your troubles" back to the metaphor, we get "lighthouse in your ocean".

So the better analogy is to say:  I will be the lighthouse in your ocean.

Comment: So by extension, Simon and Garfunkel should have sung about being someone's Bridge *in* Troubled Waters since they wished to be of use to them *in* their time of trouble? I disagree, one uses the preposition suited to the metaphor, not the one suited to to the situation being described metaphorically.

Comment: A bridge is a means of getting over something, not into it. Simon and Garfunkel wanted to be a means for the person to get  get over their troubles, Ideally the preposition suits both the metaphor and the thing described. Guide in troubles - lighthouse in ocean. Means of getting over troubles - bridge over troubles.   Of course lighthouse in the ocean doesn't make sense to people who are unaware that lighthouses are often positioned  in the ocean, but in fact they are..

Answer (score 0):

Technically the proper saying would be " i will be the lighthouse for your ocean. But of your two choices i would say - i will be the lighthouse **of** your ocean, because a lighthouse is on land next to an ocean providing a means for safe passage to those on the ocean. To say i will be the lighthouse in your ocean would imply the lighthouse is not on land but in the ocean.

Comment: Round  the British Isles, many lighthouses are in the sea, being built onto the ocean floor or to rocks. Some are sometimes in the sea and sometimes not, depending on the tide; and some are indeed built on land,